# How to get two UIFont with name same time

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uifont

I am using a font family in my application and I am trying get 2 font types like this.

```
let descriptionFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 18.0) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
let titleFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 22.0) ?? UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22.0)
```

but can't get second font.

[image]

I am changing lines position.

```
let titleFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 22.0) ?? UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22.0)
let descriptionFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 18.0) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
```

This time other font doesn't come, still second one!

[image]

I didn't understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working fine.

The problem is in your use of the variables pane while paused in the debugger. It shows variables before they have meaningful values. You have to step *past both assignments* before they will both have meaningful values. Plus, use of `let` can cause an unused value to be completely optimized away.

You might have an easier time using "caveman debugging":

```
let titleFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 22.0) ?? UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22.0)
let descriptionFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 18.0) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
print(titleFont, descriptionFont)
```

You will see that both fonts *do* have values, because we print after both assignments and we use both values.

```
<UICTFont: 0x7f87c2503b70> font-family: "Avenir-Heavy"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 22.00pt 
<UICTFont: 0x7f87c2505340> font-family: "Avenir-Book"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18.00pt
```